# How to specify paywall contents for multiple pages

Tags: google-search, googlebot, cloaking, paywall

I am reading this [guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/paywalled-content) to apply paywall contents to my website so that Google knows I am not cloaking. Unless I have misunderstood something, the example in that guide only deals with 1 particular subpage `https://example.org/article` and this way of specifying structure data seems to only apply for actual articles.

My questions are:

1/ My website has a page for each listed company in the U.S. Each page is not an actual article, most of the contents never change, only a few number get updated daily. I want to specify these company pages as paywall contents. Can I use the data structure specified in the guide above?

2/ I have thousands of company pages (`mywebsite.com/AAPL`, `mywebsite.com/GOOGL`, ...) that I want to specify as paywall contents. Do I need to type them all out in the `head` section of my website's html? In that guide I see `https://example.org/article` in the `head` section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unless I have misunderstood something, the example in that guide only deals with 1 particular subpage `https://example.org/article`

Structured data for paywalled content needs to be done on a page-by-page basis, yes.

> this way of specifying structure data seems to only apply for actual articles

According to the resource you linked, this structured data is valid for [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) or any of the following subtypes:

> - Article
> - NewsArticle
> - Blog
> - Comment
> - Course
> - HowTo
> - Message
> - Review
> - WebPage

so you can mark up your page using any of those types.

> My website has a page for each listed company in the U.S. Each page is not an actual article

The contents of your page are a `CreativeWork`. If you've got a collection of reviews of these company stocks, you could use the [Review](https://schema.org/Review) subtype. Otherwise, the more general [WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage) subtype or the `CreativeWork` type itself would suffice.

> I have thousands of company pages (mywebsite.com/AAPL, mywebsite.com/GOOGL, ...) that I want to specify as paywall contents. Do I need to type them all out in the head section of my website's html? In that guide I see `https://example.org/article` in the head section

It can go in the [head or the body](https://searchengineland.com/yes-you-can-add-json-structured-data-to-the-body-of-your-pages-321870), but it has to be a part of every individual paywalled page. How do you generate your HTML pages? I recommend constructing the JSON-LD using that same tool, whatever it is.